# How to navigate between swiftui and uikit

Tags: ios, swiftui, uikit

I need to use a third-party sdk in my swiftui project, so I jump from the swiftui view to the viewController, and this viewController asynchronously evokes an authorization page, which is obviously not in my navigation path.

So I ran into this problem:

After closing the authorization page, the expectation was that it would go back to the previous swiftui view.

But actually the program revisits the root view internally (calling the onAppear method of the root view), and the interface is fine.

I don't know what the reason is, but I guess it's because when closing the asynchronous authorization page of the viewController, the program didn't find the page it should visit, so it had to visit the root view again, but of course this is just my guess.

Now I want to know what is causing this and what should be done about it

The following is a demonstration of the core code：

```
@main
struct Demo: App {
    // Root View
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .onAppear() {
                    print("root onAppear")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView() {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink (destination: LoginView()) {
                    Text("navigate to loginView")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct LoginView: View {
    @State private var showMob: Bool = false 
    var body: some View {
        Text("click to login")
            .onTapGesture {
                self.showMob.toggle()
            }
        if showMob {
            MobLoginBridging()
                .frame(width: 0, height: 0)
        }
    }
}

struct MobLoginBridging: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = MobLoginController

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> MobLoginController {
        let controller = MobLoginController()
        return controller
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: MobLoginController, context: Context) {}
}
```

```
class MobLoginController: UIViewController, SVSDKVerifyDelegate {
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            SVSDKHyVerify.preLogin { result, err in
                if err == nil && result != nil {
                    print(result!["operator"] as Any)
                    SVSDKHyVerify.setDelegate(self)
                    
                    let mobConfig = SVSDKHyUIConfigure()
                    mobConfig.currentViewController = self // use this vc to present page
                    mobConfig.manualDismiss = true
                    
                    // open authorization page
                    SVSDKHyVerify.openAuthPage(withModel: mobConfig, openAuthPageListener: { result, err in
                        
                    }, cancelAuthPageListener: { result, err in
                        // When I close the page, this method is called and then the Root View is accessed(onAppear method is called), but the page ends up in the LoginView
                    }, oneKeyLoginListener: { result, err in
                        
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I really want to solve this problem, I hope you help, thank you!

Comment: Difficult to tell without seeing ContentView. I suppose your login view goes over your root view (fullScreen) which make it « disappear » an reappear when login is finished.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!ContentView has been completed.I seem to understand what you mean, but the login page is generated by the sdk callback, how should I control it?@PtitXav